# How to avoid resetting JSON objects in local storage on refresh?

Tags: javascript, json

New to JavaScript. I am creating a table of scores, storing them in JSON format in local storage. I'm stuck on making sure what I've saved in local storage stays there after refreshing the page.

This is how I create the JSON array:

```
var top10Scorers = {
    "top10Scorers": [
        {"position": '1', "username": 'blank', 
            "pointscore": '0', "date": 'blank'
        }
    ]
};

localStorage.setItem("top10Scorers", JSON.stringify(top10Scorers));
```

How could I rewrite this so that it doesn't reset what is in local storage every time the page is refreshed?

SOLUTION: tested to check if the key didn't exist before initialising the variable.

Comment: Should it ever get refreshed? If not, then just verify whether there's content in the variable or not

Comment: I don't understand what are you think, localStorage isn't resetting on page refresh.

Answer (score 3):

Check whether the value has been set first, if it's null, you can set it. If it's not null, you've set it before.

```
if(localStorage.getItem("top10Scorers") === null){
    // its not set, set it 
}
```

Comment: thanks, when I got round to it my solution was exactly the same as this one. wrapped it around and it worked as it should. question though, why is the comparator `===` preferred to `==` in this situation?

Comment: You use `===` instead of `==` because what if your top10Scorers value was purposefully set to a String `"null"` value? The `==` will do type conversion and will pass the `if` check. The `===` will ensure that the value has not been set before.

Answer (score 0):

Try to read the value from `localStorage` first. Only overwrite it if you don't have a value.

Comment: many thanks. I realised how to do solve my problem with this answer!